# How to store and sort dictionary in heapq?

Tags: python, heapq

I am getting below while storing dictionary in heapq. Does anyone know how to solve this ?
'<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'

```py
import heapq
PQ = []
heapq.heappush(PQ, {"1": "animal"})
heapq.heappush(PQ, {"2": "vechile"})
heapq.heappush(PQ, {"3": "music"})
print(PQ)
```

> heapq.heappush(PQ, {"2": "vechile"})
>
> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'

Comment: Dictionaries don't have any built-in ordering - how could you possibly define such a thing, given that dicts may have arbitrary numbers of keys and values?  Perhaps you want to use tuples such as `("1", "animal")`, which do have a defined ordering (first elements are compared, then the second elements if the first were equal, and so on).

Comment: @Atar new, as you seen from comments - dictionaries don't support comparison operators. Elaborate your conditions: 1) can you change the type of input items? 2) are those dicts come from the outer scope? 3) what is the expected result of utilizing heapq in your case ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest basically I am trying to use heapq in diskastra. I was storing it in dictionary format only.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few options:

- wrap your dictionaries in a class instance that defines a order over them
- convert your dictionaries to a type that already has a order

The issue is what does `{"1": "animal"} < {"2": "vechile"}` mean?

Are the keys actually priorities and the values data in which case shouldn't they be tuples or namedtuples or orderable objects. `("1", "animal") < ("2", "vechile")` has a meaning although the ordering of strings of decimals is not the same as the order of their numeric values. This is the `"10" < "2"` vs `2 < 10` issue.